# React-Native SwipeableListView not correct updating

Tags: react-native

When swiping the row in the SwipeableListView I want to delete the rowitem and re-render the list.

What is now happening is that always the last item in the list is removed, not the item that is swiped.
Any ideas what is wrong?

```
export default class SwipeList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  let ds = SwipeableListView.getNewDataSource();

  this.favourites = []

  this.state = {
    ds:[],
    dataSource:ds,

    isLoading:true,  
    closeRow:false,
   };
  }

componentWillMount () {
  store.get('KEY_FAV').then(value => {
    typeof(value) === 'object'
      ? this.favourites = Object.keys(mockdata.favourite)
      : this.favourites = JSON.parse(value)

    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.genData(this.favourites
)),
      isLoading:false
    })
  })
}


genData = (list) => {
  let dataBlob = []

  for(let i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {
    dataBlob.push({id:list[i], name:list[list[i]]})
  }
return [dataBlob, []]
}
```

Till here it is okay, the SwipeableList is loaded with all RowItems.
But in the below handleSwipeAction() while setting new state for dataSource, the list will only delete the last item, not the selected.

```
handleSwipeAction = (rowData, SectionID, rowID) => {
  AlertIOS.alert('Remove ' + rowData.name + ' \nfrom Favourites?', null, 
  [
    {text:'Cancel', onPress: () => {this.setState({closeRow:true})}, style:'cancel'},
    {text:'OK', onPress: () => {
      this.favourites.slice()
      this.favourites.splice(rowID, 1)

      this.setState({
        closeRow:true,
      })  
      this.setState({//I THINK HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.genData(this.favourites))
      })

      store.set('KEY_FAV', this.favourites)                 
    }}
  ])
}

onSwipe = (rowData, SectionID, rowID) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.actionsContainer}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.handleSwipeAction(rowData, SectionID, rowID)}>
        <Text style={styles.actionsItem}>Remove</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
   );
  };
```

and the render function

```
render() {
 if(this.state.isLoading) return null

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

      <SwipeableListView
        bounceFirstRowOnMount
        enableEmptySections={true}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        maxSwipeDistance={this.props.swipeDistance}
        renderRow={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
        renderQuickActions={this.onSwipe}
        renderSeparator={this.renderSeperator}
        doCloseRow={this.state.closeRow}
      />
  </View>
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are done `slicing`, I believe if you do:

`let ds = SwipeableListView.getNewDataSource();` all over again, and then

```
this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.genData(this.favourites)) })
```

It should work. For a reason that I still don't get. Also I don't know why you do two `setState()` in your function. One is enough no?

So this should work:

```
handleSwipeAction = (rowData, SectionID, rowID) => {
  AlertIOS.alert('Remove ' + rowData.name + ' \nfrom Favourites?', null, 
  [
    {text:'Cancel', onPress: () => {this.setState({closeRow:true})}, style:'cancel'},
    {text:'OK', onPress: () => {
      this.favourites.slice()
      this.favourites.splice(rowID, 1)

      let ds = SwipeableListView.getNewDataSource(); // add this 

      this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.genData(this.favourites)), closeRow:true })

      store.set('KEY_FAV', this.favourites) }} ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is also not working, the list is now the same as original list. No items are deleted? Reason for the two setState() is/was if I put them together in one statement they will not work.

Comment: I used to have issue with data sources not updating, and my answer was the solution. Now if you are truly declaring a new data source, and cloning it with rows with a new data, but without seeing any changes, this means the data IS NOT NEW or DID NOT CHANGE <--- debug this (your `slicing`)

Comment: Above solution is correct. The actual problem with my code was not the `setState({dataSource:..)}` , but is was the `setState({closeRow:true)}` , I changed the code of the <SwipeableListView> to be able to close a row as a prop.      `if(this.state.closeRow !== nextProps.closeRow) {
        this.setState({dataSource:this.state.dataSource.setOpenRowID(null),})
     }`. This blocked the rendering of the SwipeAbleListView.